# Improve spacing of headlines (# and ## format)

Tags: feature-request, design

Sometime I use the markdown headline `#` and `##` to structure my answers, mostly I use only use `##` since the `#` is much too big in my eyes. Furthermore in my opinion the spacing is not that good. I’d like to see more space above the headlines, especially directly behind code blocks.

## Example

This headline has the same space above and below, but it belongs to the text below so this relation should be visible in the spacing.

```
some code
```

## Headline

When using a code block right before a headline the space above seems even smaller that the space below.

Comment: with firefox 23.0.1 on a windows 7 machine, the space above the headline is slightly bigger than the space below, unless the headline follows a code block. in that case the space above and below appears equal.  however, since the space above the code block seems a bit larger than the space below the headlines, that's also sub-optimal.

Comment: May I asked if someone of the SE design team can take a look at the, since it is still wrong …